# Word2Vec не загружается. Не могу обратится по токену к вектору Word2Vec

Tags: python, nlp, word2vec

Хочу использовать вектора word2vec для обучения модели. Пишу команду:

```
from nlpia.loaders import get_data
word_vectors = get_data('w2v', limit=200000)
```

Загрузка длится вечность, так и не завершается.
Загрузил файл GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin и у меня выводит ошибку при поиске вектора по токену:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Открывал файл bin так:

```
from nltk.tokenize import TreebankWordTokenizer
from gensim.models.keyedvectors import KeyedVectors
import gzip

f = gzip.open('F:/Загрузки/GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin.gz', 'rb')
word_vectors = f.read()
f.close
```

Пытаюсь вернуть вектор этой строкой:

```
token = 'car'
word_vectors[token]
```

Выводит ошибку как на картинке.
Как мне исправить эту ошибку?

Comment: Откуда загрузили файл, почему текст программы, который выдаёт ошибку приведён картинкой, как нам воспроизводить вашу ошибку?

Comment: загрузил отсюда https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7XkCwpI5KDYNlNUTTlSS21pQmM/edit?usp=sharing, сейчас представлю код

Answer (score 2):

```
f = gzip.open('F:/Загрузки/GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin.gz', 'rb')
word_vectors = f.read()
f.close
```

Вы загрузили в переменную `word_vectors` просто массив байтов из файла. Нужно грузить данные подходящей для этого функцией, чтобы в `word_vectors` получился нужный вам тип объектов:

```
from gensim import models

word_vectors = models.KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format(
    'GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin', binary=True)
```

Пример кода я [подсмотрел](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46433778/import-googlenews-vectors-negative300-bin) на английском SO.

С загрузкой векторов через `nlpia` я пока не разобрался, запустил её в Google Colab, висит уже довольно долгое время, что-то делает.

Похоже, у `nlpia` есть [проблема](https://github.com/totalgood/nlpia/issues/29) с `Python 3.7`:

> If you use Anaconda you will be able to install nlpia in a python 3.6
> environment. It has not been tested on python 3.7 and this may be why
> it is hanging up on you. In python 3.7 the re package seems to have a
> problem with the regular expressions we use to change the filenames
> during decompression. I'll check it and make sure there's not a bug in
> get_data.

Я прервал исполнение ячейки в Google Colab, действительно вылетело на обработке регулярных выражений:

```
/usr/lib/python3.7/re.py in match(pattern, string, flags)
    173     """Try to apply the pattern at the start of the string, returning
    174     a Match object, or None if no match was found."""
--> 175     return _compile(pattern, flags).match(string)
    176 
    177 def fullmatch(pattern, string, flags=0):
```

Надо ждать, пока починят, либо использовать питон 3.6

Comment: Спасибо! Такая же проблема с колабом. А в Jupyter вообще не получается установить nlpia, пробовал различные способы.

Comment: @MaxPyankov Совместимость пакетов это вообще большая головная боль в питоне, поэтому так популярен докер и виртуальные окружения. Ставишь набор нужных версий в отдельное окружение - и всё ок. А в одной готовой среде то одна фигня не работает, то другая, сплошная засада.

Comment: можете скинуть ссылку, как это сделать? а то я не совсем понял, о чем вы.

Comment: @MaxPyankov Ну вот например: https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html А если у вас `Anaconda`, то можно её средствами виртуальные окружения создавать.